# Generated Figma plugin does not include TS typings

Tags: typescript, figma, figma-api

I'm trying to follow along with the plugin setup guide found [here](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/) and I have a very, very simple plugin that looks like this:

```
figma.showUI(__html__);

// @ts-ignore
console.log(figma.currentPage.selection[0].cornerRadius);
```

Exactly as written, the plugin works fine and returns the border radius of the selected node.

However, if I remove `// @ts-ignore` TS complains: "Property 'cornerRadius' does not exist on type 'SceneNode'."

I have installed the typings, from [here](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/#install-the-typings) and my .tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./node_modules/@figma"
  ]
}
```

}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`figma.currentPage.selection` [returns a `SceneNode` array](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/PageNode-selection/#signature). `SceneNode` doesn't have the `CornerMixin` which defines `cornerRadius`. You'll need to check that the node type is supported.

i.e. look at the `type` field on `SceneNode`:

```js
const selection = figma.currentPage.selection[0];
if (selection.type === "RECTANGLE") {
  console.log((selection as RectangleNode).cornerRadius);
}
```

The following types use `CornerMixin`, based on the typings plugin declaration file:

```js
RectangleNode
EllipseNode
PolygonNode
StarNode
VectorNode
BooleanOperationNode
```